# Does Fetch as Googlebot still support their ajax-crawling proposal?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, ajax, fetch-as-google

I spent half a day implementing the server side html generation for modal pages based on their proposal ([link](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)), but it seems like the Fetch as Googlebot functionality in Webmaster tools completely ignores the URL fragment.

I've verified that the `_escaped_fragment_` functionality is working on my server ([example](https://www.gowellpath.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/recipes)), but when I submit a URL like `/#!/recipes`, the Googlebot just fetches `/`.

There aren't any recent confirmations that it's working and, honestly, it wouldn't surprise me if they just silently dropped the functionality without even editing the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works. I have used it recently. But I would not be surprised if there are regular expressions that validate the URL input and does not allow some normally non-URL valid characters such as `#!`.

Yes, you can argue these are valid characters to use, but probably not when the fetch as Google was written. At least under normal circumstances. It may not have been updated for good reason. Normally input validation is done in your code immediately for security reasons. It may be that Google is concerned about security.

This is what I have seen. Pages submitted using fetch as Google are followed up a few days later at least. It can be as long as 2 weeks. It is best to allow the Googlebot to do it's thing. I do not like doing a fetch as Google unless I want to get a page into the index right away. And I do this just a few times a year. Otherwise, I never use fetch as Google for existing pages. I just wait.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll give it a few days and see if the actual Googlebot picks it up. Will mark yours as an answer then.